How to choose resistor capacitor values for specific frequencies
I have an array of 6 40106 square oscillators and I would like to know if there is any formula that in a given desired output frequency it will tell me which resistor and capacitor I should use?.
List of desired output frequency in relation to the fundamental osc 1:
osc 1 - fundamental 110 Hz
osc 2 - 5/4 of osc 1 (137.5Hz)
osc 3 - 3/2 of osc 1 (165Hz)
osc 4 - 147/128 of osc 1
osc 5 - 21/16 of osc 1
osc 6 -  2/1 of osc 1

How accurately do you want the frequencies held? 147/128 sounds quite precise. 1% tolerance each on the resistor, capacitor and oscillator add up to 3%, or 6% between any two frequencies as a worst case.

There is. The datasheet of TI CD40106Bcontains a formula for calculating the frequency from resistor and capacitor values. Have you not looked at the data sheet of the chip you have?
